# grounding wire extension

Tags: grounding, wire, extension

I have an above ground pool which was grounded for safety. I had to buy a new pump (motor) and unfortunately the ground wire was too short to reach the pump. I had to move the filter and pump to reach the electrical plug. Can I just add an extension so it will reach the motor or pump? I look forward to your reply.

Comment: Are you talking about the ground wire for the circuit, or the ground wire that connects the pump to the pool's bonding grid?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, typically ground wires can be extended. It's always best to replace the entire ground wire, from the connection point, instead of splicing it when possible. I'm not sure if the ground wire you are speaking of is in a flexible pipe, part of a cord or an external green wire. That information (possibly a picture) would make it much easier to answer your question thoroughly.